# Why is ActiveSupport::JSON.encode so slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

JRuby 9.2, Rails 4.2

I've been work with reading/dumping large JSON objects, 100+MB files, which would routinely hang for a few minutes then run out of memory when writing them out.

I noticed it specifically happens when using `to_json`. Below is with a 4MB file so it actually completes:

```
pry(main)> f = File.open('nvdcve-1.0-recent.json'){|f| JSON.load(f) }
pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure{ JSON.dump(f) }
  0.230000   0.010000   0.240000 (  0.081894)
=> nil
pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure{ f.to_json }
  1.020000   0.020000   1.040000 (  0.820851)
=> nil
```

The source of the problem being that ActiveSupport is overriding `to_json` on a bunch of things:

```
pry(main)> f.method(:to_json)
=> #<Method: Hash#to_json(to_json_with_active_support_encoder)>
pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure{ f.to_json_without_active_support_encoder }
  0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.035408)
pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure{ f.to_json_with_active_support_encoder }
  1.170000   0.010000   1.180000 (  0.812674)
```

See here: https://apidock.com/rails/Object/to_json_with_active_support_encoder

So what exactly is `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode` doing differently from the JSON gem's `to_json` that is causing it to be so much slower, even on an unremarkable JSON file that was loaded from a JSON file to begin with?

Would I be breaking any Rails functionality if I overrode `to_json` to not use the ActiveSupport variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [to the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb) ActiveSupport::JSON is pretty much just an additional layer on top of the JSON gem - which actually does most of the heavy lifting. What it mainly does is:

#### Escape some additional characters which can be problematic in certain browsers.

```
ESCAPED_CHARS = {
            "\u2028" => '\u2028',
            "\u2029" => '\u2029',
            ">"      => '\u003e',
            "<"      => '\u003c',
            "&"      => '\u0026',
            }
```

The comments don't state which the problematic browsers in question are and this might be a total non-issue for modern browsers.

#### Casts objects to suitable JSON representations:

```
      # Convert an object into a "JSON-ready" representation composed of
      # primitives like Hash, Array, String, Numeric,
      # and +true+/+false+/+nil+.
      # Recursively calls #as_json to the object to recursively build a
      # fully JSON-ready object.
      #
      # This allows developers to implement #as_json without having to
      # worry about what base types of objects they are allowed to return
      # or having to remember to call #as_json recursively.
      #
      # Note: the +options+ hash passed to +object.to_json+ is only passed
      # to +object.as_json+, not any of this method's recursive +#as_json+
      # calls.
      def jsonify(value)
        case value
        when String
          EscapedString.new(value)
        when Numeric, NilClass, TrueClass, FalseClass
          value.as_json
        when Hash
          Hash[value.map { |k, v| [jsonify(k), jsonify(v)] }]
        when Array
          value.map { |v| jsonify(v) }
        else
          jsonify value.as_json
        end
      end
```

This is probably the most important part as the `#as_json` is pretty much key to how models present themselves as JSON. It also handles casting dates and timestamps and other non-primitives (ActiveSupport provides `#as_json` methods for these). Removing this would most likely break a lot of things.

Depending your use case you could perhaps manually create ruby objects (arrays, hashes, etc) from your model objects and use `JSON.generate(data)` - I'm not sure it will perform better though.

Comment: By "break a lot of things" I mean that when you pass a collection of models to `render json: @things` it might not work at all - or the resulting JSON could change dramatically as the encoder may just call `#to_s` or whatever on the objects to serialize them.

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**: `ActiveSupport::JSON#encode` is doing three extra things.

1. [Calling `as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) asking each object to provide a data structure suitable for serialization.
2. ["jsonifying" that data](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L89) into JSON primitives and handling recursion.
3. [Escaping HTML in strings](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L54).

`JSON.dump` decides how things will become JSON, you have no control. The `as_json` callback allows you to control exactly how your objects are dumped. For simple objects this adds a bit of overhead. For everything else it's very important.

`jsonify` makes dumping objects easier. It chews up about 29% of the time.

> This allows developers to implement #as_json without having to worry about what base types of objects they are allowed to return or having to remember to call #as_json recursively.

Escaping HTML allows one to just plop JSON into an HTML page. That's about 38% of the time. That's of limited use for chewing up so much time. Unfortunately it can't be easily turned off. That might be a worthwhile patch.

Just 10% is spent inside the real JSON encoder. This roughly concurs with my Benchmark results.

```
[12] pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure{ ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(h) }
  1.241299   0.009459   1.250758 (  1.253938)
=> nil
[13] pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure{ JSON.dump(h) }
  0.117118   0.003333   0.120451 (  0.120881)
```

---

Note: This is with Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.3. That's what I've got, and performance issues with old versions are less interesting. You can run them yourself, I expect it to be about the same.

Running this with [`ruby-prof`](https://ruby-prof.github.io/) we can see that `JSON.dump` is spending all its time in just a few functions.

```
$ rails -e 'require "json"; require "ruby-prof"; h = File.open("nvdcve-1.0-recent.json"){|f| JSON.load(f) }; result = RubyProf.profile { JSON.dump(h) }; printer = RubyProf::GraphPrinter.new(result); printer.print(STDOUT, {})' > json.prof
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.275      0.134      0.000      0.141              1/1     <Module::JSON>#generate
  99.98%  48.78%      0.275      0.134      0.000      0.141                1     JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate 
                      0.097      0.097      0.000      0.000    401143/401143     String#encode
                      0.021      0.021      0.000      0.000    101047/101047     Hash#keys
                      0.021      0.021      0.000      0.000    213358/213358     String#to_s
                      0.001      0.001      0.000      0.000        2058/2058     Float#to_s
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.097      0.097      0.000      0.000    401143/401143     JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate
  35.26%  35.26%      0.097      0.097      0.000      0.000           401143     String#encode                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.021      0.021      0.000      0.000    101047/101047     JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate
   7.79%   7.79%      0.021      0.021      0.000      0.000           101047     Hash#keys                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.021      0.021      0.000      0.000    213358/213358     JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate
   7.77%   7.77%      0.021      0.021      0.000      0.000           213358     String#to_s                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- 49% actually generating JSON.
- 8% iterating through hash keys.
- 35% in `String#encode`, presumably to ensure all strings are `UTF-8` as required.
- 8% stringifying things.

---

Now with `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(h)`. For some reason `h.to_json` doesn't go through `encode` from the command line, but it does in console.

```
$ rails -e 'require "json"; require "ruby-prof"; h = File.open("nvdcve-1.0-recent.json"){|f| JSON.load(f) }; result = RubyProf.profile { ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(h) }; printer = RubyProf::GraphPrinter.new(result); printer.print(STDOUT, {})' > as.prof
```

It's profile is more complicated. Starting from the top.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      3.020      0.000      0.000      3.020              1/1     <Module::ActiveSupport::JSON>#encode
  96.58%   0.00%      3.020      0.000      0.000      3.020                1     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#encode /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:34
                      1.483      0.000      0.000      1.483              1/1     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#stringify
                      0.894      0.000      0.000      0.894         1/519065     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#jsonify
                      0.643      0.000      0.000      0.643         1/101047     Hash#as_json
                      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000         1/305710     Kernel#dup
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Its spending 95% of its time in [`ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#encode`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L34).

```
def encode(value)
  stringify jsonify value.as_json(options.dup)
end
```

[`value.as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) asks the value to return a data structure it wants serialized as JSON. This is scattered amongst different methods.

These don't take up a lot of time themselves, but they do recurse eating up up 21% of the total time.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.634      0.009      0.000      0.625      9800/101047     Hash#each
                      0.642      0.075      0.000      0.567     91246/101047     Array#map
                      0.643      0.000      0.000      0.643         1/101047     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#encode
  20.56%   2.69%      0.643      0.084      0.000      0.559           101047    *Hash#as_json                   /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:157
                      0.643      0.031      0.000      0.612    101047/202094     Enumerable#map
                      0.036      0.036      0.000      0.000    101047/202094     <Class::Hash>#[]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.643      0.003      0.000      0.639      10311/10311     Hash#each
  20.56%   0.11%      0.643      0.003      0.000      0.639            10311    *Array#as_json                  /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:151
                      0.643      0.051      0.000      0.592      10311/20623     Array#map
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000      1102/187785     Array#map
                      0.033      0.033      0.000      0.000    186683/187785     Hash#each
   1.05%   1.05%      0.033      0.033      0.000      0.000           187785     String#as_json                 /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:86
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.001      0.001      0.000      0.000        2058/4116     Hash#each
                      0.001      0.001      0.000      0.000        2058/4116     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#jsonify
   0.05%   0.04%      0.002      0.001      0.000      0.000             4116     Float#as_json                  /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:106
                      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000        4116/4116     Float#finite?
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[`jsonify`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L89) converts the `as_json` structure into JSON primitives. "This allows developers to implement #as_json without having to worry about what base types of objects they are allowed to return or having to remember to call #as_json recursively."
This eats up about 29% of the total time.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0.894      0.107      0.000      0.787     92348/519065     Array#map
                      0.894      0.224      0.000      0.670    426716/519065     Hash#each
                      0.894      0.000      0.000      0.894         1/519065     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#encode
  28.60%  10.59%      0.894      0.331      0.000      0.563           519065    *ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#jsonify /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:85
                      0.894      0.036      0.000      0.858    101047/202094     Enumerable#map
                      0.894      0.029      0.000      0.866      10311/20623     Array#map
                      0.193      0.129      0.000      0.064    401143/401153     Class#new
                      0.130      0.130      0.000      0.000  1104275/1104283     Module#===
                      0.031      0.031      0.000      0.000    101047/202094     <Class::Hash>#[]
                      0.001      0.001      0.000      0.000        2058/4116     Float#as_json
                      0.001      0.001      0.000      0.000        2533/5066     FalseClass#as_json
                      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000        1973/3946     TrueClass#as_json
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- [`stringify`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L105) hands all that to `JSON.generate`.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1.483      0.000      0.000      1.483              1/1     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#encode
  47.42%   0.00%      1.483      0.000      0.000      1.483                1     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#stringify /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:101
                      1.483      0.000      0.000      1.483              1/1     <Module::JSON>#generate
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`JSON.generate` calls `JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate` which eats 47% of the total time.
But 38% is spent in [`ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder::EscapedString#to_json`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L54), this method escapes HTML.
That means the time spent actually generating JSON is just 10% of the run time. This jives with the Benchmark results.

````
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1.483      0.228      0.000      1.254              1/1     <Module::JSON>#generate
  47.42%   7.31%      1.483      0.228      0.000      1.254                1     JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate 
                      1.176      0.271      0.000      0.905    401143/401143     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder::EscapedString#to_json
                      0.040      0.040      0.000      0.000    213358/213358     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder::EscapedString#to_s
                      0.037      0.037      0.000      0.000    101047/101047     Hash#keys
                      0.001      0.001      0.000      0.000        2058/2058     Float#to_s
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1.176      0.271      0.000      0.905    401143/401143     JSON::Ext::Generator::State#generate
  37.63%   8.68%      1.176      0.271      0.000      0.905           401143     ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder::EscapedString#to_json /Users/schwern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:55
                      0.614      0.209      0.000      0.405    401143/401143     ActiveSupport::ToJsonWithActiveSupportEncoder#to_json
                      0.292      0.292      0.000      0.000    401143/401143     String#gsub
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------```
````

Comment: It might be possible to disable the string escaping by monkeypatching EscapedString.